# Show popup on click

Tags: plugins, javascript

I have multiple categories on my wordpress site but few of them have large loading time, what should I do(the respective categories have multiple variations and images).

Meantime I wish to publish a popup when a user clicks on respective categories a popup comes to ask user to wait.
What should I do?

Comment: I would love to help get you pointed in the right direction, but unfortunately I'm having trouble fully understanding your questions. Would you mind to provide more information on your issues. For the first issue, do you have any caching plugins running? As this could possibly speed up the load times. Could you install the plugin [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/)? Query Monitor will allow you to see a lot of useful performance metrics. It should let you know which query(ies) are causing the slow loads and then we can start working backwards from there. For the secon

Comment: Hi, it would be better if you'd add your two questions separately so the title would be more corresponding. Also if you could add more details it will be easier to for anyone to answer.

Comment: Okay so I have 2 product categories on my Wordpress website which has a lot of variations, I need to reduce the load time of these particular categories what should I do?
https://www.apcreation.in/product/shri-mataji-photo/
this is the slow loading category